# When i click on shadowbox link it opens but is just black?

Tags: javascript, html, shadowbox

When i click a shadowbox link it opens but it's just black. Though when I use a page that doesn't exist the 404 error page does show up. The path to the page is correct

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the page you are linking to includes the stylesheets.

Mine did the same thing but it turned out the background was just black along with the text. I assume by default somehow. You can verify if this is what is happening by highlighting the box and you can see the text highlighted. If it is there, just include a stylesheet and style the page to make the text display!